# npm: command not found on amazon ec2 (even though its installed)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

- We installed NPM and created an AMI
- The elastic beanstalk uses that AMI to create an EC2
- The Procfile calls a shell script with the content pasted below.
- I am getting the error - npm : command not found (when i use the command npm manually, it works, only fails during beanstalk deploy)
- Also used the full path for npm(home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/npm), which results in permission denied
- I know its just a minor thing I am missing here, already spent few hours on this.

I tried sourcing my bash profile, which also results in permission denied.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
npm install

npm install -g serve
npm run build
nohup serve -s build > orgweb.log &
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is just a typo or did you use this exact full path
home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/npm

But if you did, there needs to be a slash before home, as in
/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v11.6.0/bin/npm